# NullReferenceException solution by redirection navigation caught up in a continuous loop

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, nullreferenceexception

everybody,

As with most of the applications, im in need to include a login page for my app if a password is set. Expected behavior of the app is that, only if a password is set, it should navigate to the passwordpage.xaml and on entering of the correct password, it should navigate to the mainpage.xaml. If the password is not set, it should directly navigate to the mainpage.xaml.

The following blog suggested that a re-navigation is needed, so as to include a check in the app.xaml.cs which determines to which page the app needs to navigate.

But the problem now is, a further navigation from the password page is not taking place. It navigates to the password page when the password is set, but then after checkin the password match, it does not move on the the mainpage.xaml, rather, it goes back to the rootframe_navigating event handler and execute the loop.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/08/28/redirecting-an-initial-navigation.aspx

This is the function in the app.xaml.cs

```
    void RootFrame_Navigating(object sender, NavigatingCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
        if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("/MainPage.xaml") != true)
            return;
        CycleManager pCycMan = CycleManager.instance;
        bool checkOk = false;
        pCycMan.ReadFromIsolatedStorage();
        if (pCycMan.GetPasswordEnabled())
        {
            checkOk = true;
        }

        e.Cancel = true;
        RootFrame.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate
        {
            if (checkOk)
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/PasswordPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));

            else
                RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        });
    }
```

And this is the function written on the button click in the passwordpage.xaml

```
    private void OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CycleManager pCycMan = CycleManager.instance;
        if (pCycMan.GetPassword() == passwordBox1.Password)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Password");
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Alfah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managd to solved it like this,

I dont know if its the right approach. but it works. First i changed the default start page to non existent page called RootPage.xaml in WMAppManifest.xaml. Then in the event handler I changed the MainPage.xaml to RootPage.xaml

```
if (e.Uri.ToString().Contains("/RootPage.xaml") != true)
          return;
```

I had to remove the password page from the backstack entry otherwise goin back to exit the app will bring the password page again.

Ref: http://www.markerstudio.com/technical/2010/09/windows-phone-7-how-to-always-launch-your-app-where-the-user-left-off/#comment-916

Alfah

Answer (score 2):

If you are going back to a page behind the page you are on, you should use the built in [`NavigationService.GoBack()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.goback.aspx) method.  This lets the phone handle the back-stack of pages.

If you need to progress forwards but never back onto a page, in Mango you now need to manually remove that page from the back-stack using [`NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Looking at your code, the navigating handler will always fire.  You seem to be checking if a password is enabled instead of if the user is authenticated.  I would simply say the logic for checking the password is wrong.

Comment: +1 here. Scrap your current approach and perform the check / redirect to passwordpage in the `Loaded` or `OnNavigatedTo` methods of the mainpage. Then `GoBack()` when password is set.

Comment: @adam GoBack() cannot be used, since there is no entry in the back stack,ie it has not navigated to the mainpage.xaml yet. It checks condition in the app.xaml, then moves on to the password page and then it should move to the mainpage.xaml but it does not move to the mainpage.xaml

Comment: @alfah That is likely because you are trying to cancel a navigation event and start a new one in the same chunk of code.  Try making the password page your start page so you don't need to hijack the navigation handler... the users first sight will simply be a login page.  You can then navigate forwards and pop the password page from the back-stack and everything from then on should be normal behaviour.

Comment: @ChrisSainty but why do we need to unneccesarily load the mainpage.xaml if no password is set?

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth If the password is not set, I need not show the passwordpage, jus the mainpage.xaml, so some kind of check is needed right? It was suggested to Cancel current navigation and schedule the real navigation for the next tick since we can't navigate immediately as that will fail. no overlapping navigations are allowed either.

Comment: @alfah Yeah I see that now.  It is simply your password checking logic in the navigating handler that is incorrect.  I would surmise that when you try to navigate to main from the password page, the handler is again firing, `GetPasswordEnabled` again returns `true` and you go back to the password page again.

Comment: @alfah Simplicity. To fix the code you have I would say only cancel and renavigate when going to password page, let your MainPage call simply carry on firing the navigation it is already doing.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth yea. . thats precisely what is happening, if the password enabled returns true, i need to go to the passwordpage else mainpage. So how do i fix this?

Comment: @ChrisSainty you mean if(checkok){e.cancel = true; RootFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/PasswordPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));}

Comment: @alfah Like how you check if it's enabled, you need to save whether the user has already entered it before and add that to your check.